# How to access external website using Geb

Tags: grails, groovy, geb, gherkin

I am automating my project using Geb and Groovy. For Example: I am logging into Gmail and I define different Pages as - Inbox, Sent Item, Trash, Drafts, etc. Now in my spec I wanted to access an external website like yahoomail. How can I define it the spec to access an external Webiste.
I use "go" to navigate to yahoo mail as below in my spec

```
    then: "I go to Yahoo mail page"
    go "https://login.yahoo.com/"

    and: "Signing into Yahoo mail "
    at YahooLoginPage
```

In the YahooLoginPage.groovy it is not finding the Next button which I define as static at

```
static at = { $("#login-signin") }
```

Error message I get :

Condition not satisfied:

go "https://login.yahoo.com/"

|

null

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: There are a few things in the question that don't make sense to me but one thing is that one would normally not invoke `go` in a `then` block.

Comment: browser method 'to' does return an 'at checked' page instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using [a method which has a void return type](http://gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/Browser.html#go(java.lang.String)) in a `then:` Spock block. Every statement is asserted in `then:` blocks and that method call evaluates to `null` because of its return type and hence the failure you're getting.

Basically you should not use Geb's `go()` method in a `then:` - use it in in a `given:` or `when:` block instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think Erdi's and Jeff's answers above nail it, but since I was curious to find out if it was possible and for an example of how working code might look I went ahead and built a freestanding groovy script which runs a geb spec. The below script enters a username in the yahoo login flow and hits the next button.

```
@Grapes([
  @Grab("org.gebish:geb-spock:2.1"),
  @Grab("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4"),
  @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.52.0"),
  @GrabExclude('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all')
])

import geb.*
import geb.spock.*
import spock.util.EmbeddedSpecRunner
import java.util.logging.*
import org.w3c.css.sac.ErrorHandler
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.SilentCssErrorHandler

new EmbeddedSpecRunner().runClass(YahooSpec)

class YahooSpec extends GebReportingSpec {
    def setup()  {
      // disable css errors output - don't do this for real tests
      browser.driver.webClient.cssErrorHandler = new SilentCssErrorHandler()
    }

    def "should be able to enter username at yahoo"() {
      when: "I go to Yahoo mail page"
        to YahooLoginPage

      then: "there should be a button with value 'Next'"
        nextButton.value() == "Next"

      when: "I enter a username and click next"
        username = "BobbaFett"
        nextButton.click()

      then: "I should end up at the password page"
        at YahooPasswordPage
        greeting.text() == "Hello BobbaFett"
    }
}

class YahooPasswordPage extends Page { 
  static url = "https://login.yahoo.com/account/challenge/password"
  static at  = { title.trim() == "Yahoo" }

  static content = {
    greeting                          { $("h1", class: "username")}
  }
}

class YahooLoginPage extends Page { 
  static url = "https://login.yahoo.com/"
  static at  = { title == "Yahoo - login" }

  static content = {
    username                          { $("input#login-username")}
    nextButton(to: YahooPasswordPage) { $("input#login-signin")  }
  }
}
```

saving the above in a file `test.groovy` and running:

```
~> groovy test.groovy
```

executes the spec. It should be noted that the first run will take some time as the script is downloading dependencies. It should also be noted that using a username which does not exist will break the test as the test assumes that yahoo will send you to the password page after hitting next.

Tested on:

```
Groovy Version: 2.4.15 JVM: 1.8.0_161 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X
```